# R lazyeval: pass parameters to dplyr::filter

Tags: r, filter, parameters, dplyr, lazyeval

I think this questions has multiple other variations (eg: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783396/passing-arguments-to-dplyr-summarize-function?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973056/in-r-pass-column-name-as-argument-and-use-it-in-function-with-dplyrmutate-a)  and perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr)) - probably even an answer somewhere.

How to provide parameters to the filter function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
set.seed(10)
data <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10, 100, T))
```

If I need to count the number of occurrences of the number 1 through 10 occurs and show the count for, say 1, 2 and 3, I would do this:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(a < 4)
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     n
  <int> <int>
1     1    11
2     2     8
3     3    16
```

Now, how can I put this into a function ?
Here `grp` is the grouping var.

```
   fun <- function(d, grp, no){
      d %>% 
        group_by_(grp) %>% 
        summarise_(n = interp(~ n() )) %>%
        filter_( grp < no)
        # This final line instead also does not work:  
        # filter_(interp( grp < no), grp = as.name(grp))
    }
```

Now,

```
fun(data, 'a', 4)
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 0 × 2
# ... with 2 variables: a <int>, n <int>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the quosures approach from the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released 0.6.0)

```
fun <- function(d, grp, no){
   grp <- enquo(grp)

   d %>% 
      group_by(UQ(grp)) %>% 
      summarise(n = n() )%>%
       filter(UQ(grp) < no)

}

fun(data, a, 4)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    11
#2     2     8
#3     3    16
```

We use `enquo` to take the input argument and convert it to `quosure`, within the `group_by/summarise/mutate`, the quosure is evaluated by unquoting (`UQ` or `!!`)

---

The above function can be also modified to take both quoted and unquoted arguments

```
fun <- function(d, grp, no){
   lst <- as.list(match.call())
   grp <- if(is.character(lst$grp)) {
              rlang::parse_quosure(grp)
            } else enquo(grp)


   d %>% 
      group_by(UQ(grp)) %>% 
      summarise(n = n() )%>%
       filter(UQ(grp) < no)

}




fun(data, a, 4)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    11
#2     2     8
#3     3    16

 fun(data, 'a', 4)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    11
#2     2     8
#3     3    16
```

Comment: That is very smart, and rather simple in syntax - I guess I will have to get i tfrom github (@hadley/dplyr)